# Resources for the study of the environment of Laramidia in the Late Cretaceous

Tags: palaeontology, dinosaurs

I'm looking for resources (book, web, article, etc.) to learn in detail about the environment of Laramidia in the late Cretaceous, including flora, fauna, landscape, and climate. My goal is to get a picture of what it would be like to step out of a time machine into the North American West during the Maastrichian not long before the mass extinction event that ended the dinosaurs, and hopefully get an idea of how that environment varied by region. So far I've only been able to turn up [a few brief articles](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2017/sep/27/a-glimpse-of-when-canadas-badlands-were-a-lush-dinosaur-forest-by-the-sea), and [some dense scientific reports](https://pubs.usgs.gov/pp/1561/report.pdf) (which I read the relevant parts of, but as a layman working without the benefit and context of professional knowledge have been of limited use).

I'm aware this question has some crossover with Earth sciences. But as it might fit pretty well on either site, and I've seen you folks answer more paleontology questions, I'd be grateful if you'd entertain it here.

**How can I effectively research the environment of Late Cretaceous Laramidia?** (Information directly about Laramidia is also very welcome, if secondary.)